# A question regarding Brian M. Scott's proof that $\text{cf}(\aleph_{\omega_1})=\omega_1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, cardinals, ordinals

> $\text{cf}(\aleph_{\omega_1})=\omega_1$

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1393854/368425), I quote Brian M. Scott's proof:

> Suppose that $\langle\alpha_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ is an increasing sequence cofinal in $\omega_{\omega_1}$. For each $\xi<\omega_1$ there is a least $n(\xi)\in\omega$ such that $\omega_\xi\le\alpha_{n(\xi)}$. Clearly there is then an $m\in\omega$ such $X=\{\xi<\omega_1:n(\xi)=m\}$ is uncountable, and it follows easily that $\color{blue}{\omega_{\omega_1}=\sup_{\xi\in X}\omega_\xi}\le\alpha_m<\omega_{\omega_1}$, which is absurd.

I would like to ask what is the reasoning behind $\color{blue}{\omega_{\omega_1}=\sup_{\xi\in X}\omega_\xi}$.

> I think we can prove $X$ is cofinal in $\omega_1$ from the fact that $X\subseteq \omega_1$ and $|X|=\omega_1$. I have tried but unsuccessfully.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since a countable union of countable sets is countable, a countable partition of an uncountable set has one part (at least) uncountable. Yes choice is used, and is necessary.

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila, did you mean that to prove the existence of such set $X$, we must use the theorem *a countable union of countable sets is countable*, which in turn appeals to Axiom of Countable Choice?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Countable choice is needed.

Comment: Thank you so much @AsafKaragila, I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every initial segment of $\omega_1$ is countable, so $X$ is unbounded in $\omega_1$

---

Like Asaf commented, the fact that there exists such $X$ require choice, without some kind of choice it is not necessarily correct

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything is now clear.

Comment: It is unfortunate that I forget an useful property that *an initial segment of an ordinal is an ordinal*.